# Notification sound does not work after updating app version

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have several notification channels in my app.
For each channel, I assigned a sound Uri to a file stored in my app `res/raw` folder.

Like so

```
// Getting the sound Uri
int resID = context.getResources().getIdentifier(soundItem.getSoundFileName(), "raw", context.getPackageName());
        if (resID != 0) {
            return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getContext().getPackageName() + "/" + resID);
        }
```

```
 // Creating Channel
NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(androidChannelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Creating an Audio Attribute
        AudioAttributes audioAttributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION)
                .build();
        notificationChannel.setSound(soundUri, audioAttributes);
```

This worked great in several versions, however, in the last version of my app, we noticed that notifications are not playing sound anymore.

Digging and debugging, and I found that the res ID for the sound file has changed.
So, if for example in version 1.2 of my app `R.raw.tone1` was `12345678`, now that same `R.raw.tone1` is `123456799`.
Which results in that the system can't find the file anymore.

Now I'm not sure what should I do? Recreate the channel each version?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the sound resource instead. Then you only have to create a new channel once, in the next update (and delete the old one).

```
 // using scope function to make sure resource exists in compile time
        val soundUri = R.raw.tone1.run {
            Uri.parse(
                "${ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE}://"
                    .plus("${context.packageName}/raw/tone1")
            )
        }
```